# Finding unique data grids in sql

Tags: sql, bigdata

I want to find unique data sets using sql (think groups of rows that form unique data sets, find and eliminate duplicates). Grouping is to be done on parent_id, key_id, key_value_id. But uniqueness needs to be determined by considering data both horizontally and vertically. The data size runs into terra bytes.

As an example, I have following data in a table -

```
parent_id   key_id  key_value_id    id     value
601         null       null         601     S
601         null       null         602     5

601         null       null         601     S
601         null       null         602     5
601         null       null         610     TYPE B

16501       16502       3           16501   -
16501       16502       3           16508   ?

601         null       null         601     S
601         null       null         602     5

16501       16502       3           16501   -
16501       16502       3           16508   3
```

The expected result is as below -

```
parent_id   key_id  key_value_id    id     value
601         null       null         601     S
601         null       null         602     5

601         null       null         601     S
601         null       null         602     5
601         null       null         610     TYPE B

16501       16502       3           16501   -
16501       16502       3           16508   ?

16501       16502       3           16501   -
16501       16502       3           16508   3
```

This data set/grid was repeated and hence removed.

```
601         null       null         601     S
601         null       null         602     5
```

This is to be considered as separate data set due to an extra row in the set -

```
601         null       null         601     S
601         null       null         602     5
601         null       null         610     TYPE B
```

One option is to use cursors but the size of data is huge and this may not be a performant solution. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

Any help/ pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is set based, but generally order in not important. How about using the MINUS operator to compare the 2 queries above. If you want something more complex than this you'll need to give more details of your queries, requirements and the database engine you are using.

PS MINUS is used in Oracle, I think SQLServer uses EXCEPT

Comment: Database used is SQL Server. I don't have 2 two data sets on which I can perform set operation. The first block shows how my problem data is, in that block itself there are chunks of duplicate datasets, I need to eliminate the duplicate datasets. The second block shows the expected result once the elimination has been done.